# Having trouble with M2 2.1.0-rc3 upgrade through web tool

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I am getting the following confusing message when trying to update from M2 2.0.7 to M2 2.1.0-rc3:

> Completed! You need to resolve these issues to continue.
>   Check Updater Application Availability
>   Updater application is available.
>
> Check Cron Scripts
>   Cron script readiness check passed.
>
> Check Component Dependency
>   We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail
>
> Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>   - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0-rc3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.0-rc3].
>   - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0-rc3 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> For additional assistance, see component dependency help .
>
> PHP Version Check
>   Your PHP version is correct (7.0.7-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1).
>
> PHP Settings Check
>   Your PHP settings are correct.
>
> PHP Extensions Check
>   You meet 15 out of 15 PHP extensions requirements. Show detail

As you can see my php 7.07 version check passes and all necessary extensions are available, but, the component dependency check is barfing on my php version. Not sure how to address this.

As an aside, the same php version worked just fine with upgrading to 2.0.7 and all upgrades to this point. I haven't made any changes to any php related files at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the dependency is wrong in the magento/product-community-edition, you should open an Issue on github to tell Magento.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues

Answer (score 0):

Issue ultimately was that php 5.5.9 was still linked in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled even after installing 7.0.7. I deleted the links and then re-linked to php7 and everything straightened itself out.

In ubuntu 14.04 the apt-get install php7.0 command only updates the /usr/local/php links. It does NOT update the apache stuff. It creates the php7.0.conf and php7.0.load files but leaves them in /etc/apache2/mods-available without linking them to mods-enabled.